# Hung sshd connections

Tags: linux, ssh

Our linux server has something like 50 "zombie" ssh connections... I cannot restart the machine right now and I would really rather not have to kill each one by PID. I'm also not sure if killall will kill the actual service and prevent me from logging back in. Is there a simple way to kill them? Where should I set a timeout to prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably write a quick script and run it with `nohup`.  Without nohup, your loss of connection would cause the script to quit running due to bash's SIGHUP on exit.  `nohup` will make the script immune to sighups.

```
#!/bin/bash
killall sshd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/sshd start
```

To be extra safe, if you can't test the script on a system you have local access to, I would enable an alternate means of connecting.

Another method would be to parse out the pids.  For example..

`ps ax | grep ssh | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/pids`

Then, look at `w` to determine what tty your shell is using.  Look for the instance running `w`.  Once determined, run `ps aufx` to figure out which sshd instance is assigned to your identified tty.  Then remove that pid from /tmp/pids.  After that, process the script to add kill.

`sed -i 's/^/kill /g' /tmp/pids`

Then, execute it..

`sh /tmp/pids`

For timing out idle SSH connections after 5 minutes, you can specify the following in sshd_config:

```
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

Or, you can set the `TMOUT` variable in `/etc/profile` with `bash`.  If sshd loses its shell, it will terminate.